# Is HP LeanFT more a DevTester Tool

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, hp-uft, testcomplete

We are preparing a comparative document for three test tools

1. Selenium
2. Test Complete
3. HP Lean FT

Have successfully created a comparative document with lots of comparisons. But there are certain points that we are not finding anywhere on online resources available.

1. Is HP LeanFT more a DevTester Tool?
2. What level of Programming skills needed to use the Tool (can the testers use it, or need to have very good developing skills?)
3. Did not found any online resource to start with using LeanFT in Visual Studio for C#? can anyone share if available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as LeanFT does not include the record and playback functionality that full UFT does.  Saying that all of these tools will require programming skills to some degree to get the most out of them.

If you Google LeanFT C# there are a number of resources and tutorials avaliable unless I'm missing something?

Comment: did not found much resource for the following points as well.
1. Does LEANFT support integration with DeviceFarms
2. Which frameworks does LEANFT support or can be integrated with.
3. Does LEANFT support BrowserStack
4. Support to Record by default or by Scripting?